# Dynamically setting the default selected item in a RadioGroup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I cannot get the RadioGroup component to select the default value on render when it is passed as a prop. Everything works fine if I hardcode the name of the item into the defaultValue property based on the console.log output of props.currentBookmark.

Here is the code snippet. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';
export default function CustomizedRadios(props) {
  
    const onChange = (event) => {
        props.onChange(event)
    }
    
  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <FormLabel component="legend"></FormLabel>
      {console.log(props.currentBookmark)}
      <RadioGroup defaultValue={props.currentBookmark} aria-label="gender" name="customized-radios" onChange={onChange}>
          {props.bookmarkList.map(function (bookmark)  {return (<FormControlLabel value={bookmark.name} editable={true} control={<StyledRadio />} label={bookmark.name} /> )})}
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Stackoverflow forced me to  split the code - so here is a missing part, but I guess it is irrelevant to the issue I am having:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
  },
  icon: {
    borderRadius: '50%',
    width: 16,
    height: 16,
    boxShadow: 'inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(16,22,26,.2), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(16,22,26,.1)',
    backgroundColor: '#f5f8fa',
    backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(180deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.8),hsla(0,0%,100%,0))',
    '$root.Mui-focusVisible &': {
      outline: '2px auto rgba(19,124,189,.6)',
      outlineOffset: 2,
    },
    'input:hover ~ &': {
      backgroundColor: '#ebf1f5',
    },
    'input:disabled ~ &': {
      boxShadow: 'none',
      background: 'rgba(206,217,224,.5)',
    },
  },
  checkedIcon: {
    backgroundColor: '#137cbd',
    backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(180deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.1),hsla(0,0%,100%,0))',
    '&:before': {
      display: 'block',
      width: 16,
      height: 16,
      backgroundImage: 'radial-gradient(#fff,#fff 28%,transparent 32%)',
      content: '""',
    },
    'input:hover ~ &': {
      backgroundColor: '#106ba3',
    },
  },
});

// Inspired by blueprintjs
function StyledRadio(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Radio
      className={classes.root}
      disableRipple
      color="default"
      checkedIcon={<span className={clsx(classes.icon, classes.checkedIcon)} />}
      icon={<span className={classes.icon} />}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: can you also share how you are calling this component and sending props. So, that it gives us more details to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

For input params:

```
const bookmarkList = [
  {
    name: "Bookmark 0"
  },
  {
    name: "Bookmark 1"
  },
  {
    name: "Bookmark 2"
  }
];
```

Something like:

```
...
...
{props.bookmarkList.map((bookmark, index) => {
  return (
    <FormControlLabel
      key={bookmark}
      value={bookmark.name}
      editable={true}
      control={<StyledRadio />}
      label={bookmark.name}
      // Default is selected by bookmark.name
      //checked={bookmark.name === 'Bookmark 1'}
      // Default is selected by index
      checked={index === 1}
    />
  );
})}
...
...
```

Comment: Indeed it sets a default - though now it is multiple choice. When I click on different bookmark the previous one is checked as well.

Answer (score 2):

After a suggestion from previous answer I made some modifications:

```
export default function CustomizedRadios(props) {
  
    const onChange = (event) => {
        props.onChange(event)
    }
    
  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <FormLabel component="legend"></FormLabel>
      {console.log(props.currentBookmark)}
      <RadioGroup defaultValue={props.currentBookmark} aria-label="gender" name="customized-radios" onChange={onChange}>
          {props.bookmarkList.map(function (bookmark)  {return (<FormControlLabel key={bookmark} value={bookmark.name} checked={(bookmark.name == props.currentBookmark)? props.currentBookmark:false} editable={true} control={<StyledRadio />} label={bookmark.name} /> )})}
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Dynamically calculated prop value to clear out previous selection:

checked={(bookmark.name == props.currentBookmark)? props.currentBookmark:false}

... and new value of currentBookmark set by a parent component callback:

onChange={onChange}

Works exactly how I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If your value is a number then convert this number into the string using toString()